# Add t('String to be translated') to your database

Tags: i18n-l10n

I've altered a form where I set the save button text to `t("Buy Product")`;

But how can I make sure that I can translate this string in **admin/config/region/translate/translate** ?

I've tried to add this

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
 'Buy Product' => 'Koop Product',
);
```

to my settings.php but no result. How can I make sure the string in my code can be translated in drupal itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every single string passed to `t($string)` function will be added to the database, and you can find it in the path you montioned above `"admin/config/regional/translate/translate"`

clear the cache, and search it again with help of filters existing on the admin translate page.

**[EDIT]**

First of all a must have module in multilangual sites is the [internationalization](https://drupal.org/project/i18n) module, it's a powerfull and helpfull module...

**But the most important thing in your case** is that before you can see your string in the transltion page:

1. you must enable(switch to) the desired language
2. visit the page that contain that needle string
3. visit again the translation interface.

That's it you will find your string ;)

Comment: I've added t('factuur') in a custom module (which is enabled). Cleared my cache and check but when I search for string factuur I get no results (filters show all fields with equal to factuur). I don't have to install an extra module or something no?

Comment: I have updated the post hope that is clear enough :)